# How to configure DocumentSymbol in a custom language in VSCode so that sticky scroll works?

Tags: vscode-extensions

I have a [custom language extension](https://github.com/nachocab/vscode-nacho-language/tree/master) and I've added `folding: {offSide: true}` to my [language-configuration.json](https://github.com/nachocab/vscode-nacho-language/blob/master/language-configuration.json#L42). It appears to work, but only for a second:

[image]

As soon as the outline panel is loaded, the sticky scroll disappears.

I think this happens because I'm responding to the `textDocument/documentSymbol` request in [extension.ts](https://github.com/nachocab/vscode-nacho-language/blob/master/src/extension.ts#L29) incorrectly (these are [the only docs I found](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/language-extensions/programmatic-language-features#show-all-symbol-definitions-within-a-document)).

I've tried using `new vscode.DocumentSymbol` but it doesn't seem to make any difference:

```js
symbols.push(
  new vscode.DocumentSymbol(
    name,
    "Heading",
    vscode.SymbolKind.Field,
    line.range,
    line.range
  )
);
```

I'm all out of ideas. I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is that VSCode doesn't properly implement sticky scroll when the range in the Document symbol only expands one line.

Using proper ranges and DocumentSymbols with children, [it works](https://github.com/nachocab/vscode-nacho-language/blob/master/src/extension.ts#L83).